# Two kind of outputs for same code in linkedlist with python

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
    else:
        n = self.head
        while n.ref is not None:
            n = n.ref
        n.ref = new_node
```

** output -> 30 20 10**

- if i execute this code o/p is right *

  ```
    else:
        while self.head.ref is not None:
            self.head = self.head.ref
        self.head.ref = new_node
  ```

** output -> 30 10**

- if i execute this code o/p is skiping middle numbers and executing only last one. *

Comment: It's not the same code, `self.head` got reassigned in the second, thus mutating the linked list (in probably an unintended/unexpected way; no idea for us to tell without the rest of the code), first version made no such mutation.

Answer (score 0):

In the second part of your code, you're basically reassigning the head of the linked list. That is why you are getting different results.
It has something to do with Python's Namespaces and how it assigns a variable name to an object (eg. an int, a float, ...).
In the first code, you have `n` which refers to the linked list's head. Then again in the loop, you reassign another reference to `n`. You are telling python to ignore the previous object that `n` referred to and point to another object.
However in the second code, you are changing the head of the linked to it's next object reference. This is why you are getting two different results.